shrinking a cylinder
Let $M_s$ be smooth Riemannian manifolds each with finite unique positive volumes, with $M_s$ mutually diffeomorphic to $S^1 \times (0,1)$ with warped metric $g_s(t,x)=\psi_s(x)dt^2+\phi_s(t)dx^2.$ Can the one parameter warping functions determine a prescribed asymptotic geometric evolution of $M_s$? Prescription I had in mind is that $S^1\times (0,1)$ should be doubly pinched at the ends but otherwise smooth, and  $\lim_{s \to \infty}\mathrm{vol}(M_s)\to 0.$
I think this is unlikely because $\psi,\phi$ can only warp the geometry in certain ways. Naïvely, the asymptotic shrinking of volumes of $M_s$ suggests a kind of Ricci flow or mean curvature (a radial shrinking) flow with the additional criterion of fixed (in space) singularities of the desired metric. For me I am struggling to come up with explicit conditions that ensure the doubly pinched ends (singularities of the metric) remain at a fixed distance from each other. Possibly Dirichlet boundary conditions could play? This is because Dirichlet boundary conditions would fix those singularities in space.

Is it possible to select warping functions as in $g_s(t,x)$ to achieve the desired geometric evolution of $M_s$, while avoiding, or not necessarily delving into the machinery of geometric PDE's and Dirichlet bondary conditions? Would more parameters in the warping functions remedy the situation?

